# How to put Control Objects of Manipulate into Opener View

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I am attempting to put a control object of `Manipulate[]` into an `OpenerView[]` which will allow me to hide and show controls.  The code below doesn't do what I want... but it should give you an idea of what I want.

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x] + a, {x, -3, 3}],

 OpenerView[{"Open to Control a", {a, 1, 4, ControlType -> Slider}}]]
```

This is suppose to open and close an openerview to hide and show the controller for a.  But I can't get the slider to appear.  Below is picture of the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x] + a, {x, -3, 3}],
 OpenerView[{"open to control ", Control[{{a, 1, "a"}, 0, 10, 1}]}]
 ]
```

Comment: Yes!  Spent a couple hours on this and figured it out right after I posted it.  lol.   It seems like a good question that others might want to know the answer to so I'll leave it posted.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I spoke to soon.  I figured it out.  I'll leave this here for anyone that has the same question.

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x] + a, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> 2], 
 OpenerView[{"Open to Control a", 
   Control[{{a, 1, "a"}, 1, 8, Slider}]}]]
```